# Site Visitor Can't See Site Background

Tags: permissions, theme

I have a user who is only a member of Site Visitors group. The site has a custom background applied and saved to Site Assets library. Site Visitors *do have the access* to the Site Assets library, however, when the user who is the member of this group accesses the site, no background is rendered.

Site background is set using "Change the Look" option from the Site Settings. The default modern theme is just modified with this background.

How do I make the background render for all users, including Site Visitors?

Comment: Could it be possible that the user is seeing a cached version of the page? Please force a full refresh of the page.

Comment: Is the background picture check out? Did you publish a major version when uploading it?